# Run javascript function when replaceWith finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery `replaceWith` call, and **I want to pop up an alert only when the replaceWith finishes loading**.

To achieve this I have this very naive javascript implementation:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#myDiv").click(function () {
    
    $("#myDiv").replaceWith("<div>Hello World!!!</div>");
    
    alert("done");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">Hello!</div>
```

The problem is that in this case the alert will pop-up independently of the time that the `replaceWith` takes. If it is fast, no problem, but if the `replaceWith` takes several seconds to load (which is the real case) then the pop-up appears way before, and I want to avoid that.

How can I achieve the behaviour I am looking for?

Comment: Can you add the circumstances in which `replaceWith` would take that amount of time?  Even then, JavaScript is single threaded, so the alert will not appear until the function has returned.

Comment: Define your 'several-seconds-action' as a promise, and move `alert` (or whatever action you'd like to take) in its 'done' callback.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The problem is that the call to the server that will return the data used by `replaceWith` takes several seconds and is big. Thus, there will always be a delay due to fetching the data, and then loading it to the client. Imagine you are fetching a big image and loading on the client. You would want to have the image completely loadded before doing any changes to it :D

Comment: @raina77ow: I am quite new to thise jQuery and javascript thing. What is a promise? How can I use one?

Comment: ah, now we're getting somewhere :)  As @raina77ow says - you need to put your code in a callback of the call that's getting the data.    `replaceWith` itself isn't taking several seconds, it's whatever you're doing before that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $("body");
  $("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    var html =  $("<div>Hello World!!!</div>");
    $("#myDiv").replaceWith(html)
      .promise().done(function(elem) {
        if (body.find(html).is("*") 
            && !body.find(elem).is("*")) {
               alert("done");
        }
      });    
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $("body");
  $("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    var html = $("<img src=http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-1920-1920-2.jpg />");
        
        // $("<div>Hello World!!!</div>"); 

       
    $("#myDiv").replaceWith(html)
      .promise().done(function(elem) {
        if (body.find(html).is("*") 
            && !body.find(elem).is("*")) {
               alert("done");
        }
      });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">Hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try getting the value of what you're replacing - then check if it exists after the replacement - then you can alert its complete.

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eavxkc3f/

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(".myDiv").click(function () {

      var currentItem = $(".myDiv").html();
      var replacer = "<div>Hello World!!!</div>";

      $(".myDiv").replaceWith("<div>Hello World!!!</div>");

      if($(".myDiv").html != currentItem){
          alert("Done.");
      }

  });
});
```

Comment: `$(".myDiv").html` is a function and it always not equal string

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [**DOM MutationObserver**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) spec, I think it does what you want. Register it on a target node, and it will watch for changes beneath that target.

It's an updated version of the now deprecated [**Mutation events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

A [blog post with additional good info](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) (and where I found this sample code)

Working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwyyb3hg/9/) (code below)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#myDiv").click(function () {
    $("#myDiv").replaceWith("<div>Hello World!!!</div>");
  });
});

// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#divParent');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    //console.log(mutation.type);
      alert('Done');
  });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();
```